# Should I allow a SQL WHERE clause as a REST API parameter, available on the internet?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, ruby, security

The project I'm working on has a REST API written in JRuby/Java, with an endpoint that hits a MySQL database to retrieve a number of records.

We need to allow the client to filter those records using one or more columns, including boolean checks and range values.

The easiest way we can do this is to add a string parameter to the API, then add it into the SQL statement.

Collectively, the development team agree that this is a bad idea but the alternative is to provide an almost identical syntax for filtering, which is translated into SQL. The allure of the SQL injection parameter is strong.

**So my question is, are there any circumstances under which this is a safe thing to do?**

In particular, might we consider using the WHERE clause safely if it's been fully parsed beforehand, and identified as such. Or at the very least, checking for certain trigger words such as DROP, SELECT etc.

Also if anyone knows of a good library that could act as a go-between (translating or parsing an external expression into a WHERE clause) that would be great.

Comment: Don reinvent the wheel. The OData and GData protocols already provide this functionality. BTW scrubbing a WHERE clause is a lot more vulnerable to SQL injection than a properly designed filter syntax

Comment: sql injection's a problem only if you don't know how to avoid it. checking for particular keywords is definitely **NOT** a way to avoid it. it's exactly the WRONG thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

The OData and GData protocols already implement this functionality in a safe and standard way. You can find server and client implementations for both, for Ruby, PHP, MySQL etc. Check [here](http://www.odata.org/libraries#MySQL) for the OData libraries

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the SQL injection issue, you'll expose your inner implementation (both the database chosen - MySQL *and* your table structure) directly in the form of your API.

e.g. if you change to some NoSQL-type implementation at the backend, your public-facing API will break immediately. Similarly if you restructure your database. I wouldn't do this even in an environment in which I wasn't worried about the probability/severity of injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the security implications, allowing an arbitrary WHERE clause is a bad idea because it takes the "I" out of "API" -- it's not an interface. The API is supposed free the user of the need to know details of the implementation. Like table and column names.

If clients are interacting with your data by constructing their own WHERE clauses, then you can *never change the database*. There might be code out there with those statements programmed in. If a bug or new feature required you to alter the DB in a way that would break existing client interactions you'd be stuck. The API should provide the filtering capability and translate requests into calls to backend in a way that lets you change the backend without breaking the API.

Comment: Good point. My main worry was around the security, but this is also a serious shortcoming. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ORM's for this purpose, especially in ruby (activerecord, sequel)

The most basic thing you need to do is escape the string input, which will pretty much prevent sequel injection if you are doing it properly.

It helps to not directly insert parameters directly into the sequel statement if you dont have to either, instead, check their validity and then map them to logical ones (this isn't always possible). For example, if there is an html dropdown list, and when you submit the form it passes some parameter 'firstitem', map 'firstitem' to an id or otherwise that you will then use to search on, versus using the user supplied version (assuming this mapping doesn't involve the db).